# limiting the number of posts to display on subpages-blogger

Tags: blogger

i am using blogger.
my question is regarding to labels.
in my blog.i have created one menu bar. in which 
one list element contains inline element (SUB MENU) and have attached the label url to it. 
like:

```
<div class='nav-collapse collapse'>
<ul class='nav' id='menu-primary'>
<li><a class='act' href='http://avandrewmaterials.blogspot.in/index.html'    style='color:#fff;'>Home</a></li>

<li class='dropdown'><a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'  href='#'>Android<i class='icon-angle-down'/></a>
<ul class='dropdown-menu'>
<li><a  href='http://avandrewmaterials.blogspot.in/search/label/Android%20basics'>Android Basics</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='dropdown'><a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>Java<i class='icon-angle-down'/></a>
<ul class='dropdown-menu'>
<li><a href='http://avandrewmaterials.blogspot.in/search/label/Java%20Tutorials'>Java Tutorials</a></li><li><a      href='http://avandrewmaterials.blogspot.in/search/label/Java%20Projects'>Java Projects</a></li></ul>
</li>
<li><a href='http://avandrewmaterials.blogspot.in/p/contact-us.html' style='color:#0000;'>Contact Us</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

so, my question is,
whenever i click on java tutorials(SUB MENU) it shows all the post. but i want to limit it so that it will only display 5 posts per page.

any idea? please help.
because, on google, there are many tutorials but to limiting post displayed on main page.

i have tried some code as:

replacing

expr:href='data:label.url'

to

expr:href='data:label.url + "?&max-results=5"'

but it only works on label widget.
its not working if you are using label url in menu.

plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace ampersand sign `&` with `&amp;`

```
<a href='http://avandrewmaterials.blogspot.in/search/label/Java%20Tutorials?&amp;max-results=5'></a>
```